# Set default program for MIME type: image/*

Tags: mime-types, xdg

Is there really no way to set the default program for all MIME sub-types of a top-level type? E.g., `image/*`.

I am talking about the XDG MIME spec, and not the older mailcap scheme. And I'm not asking about alternate way to achieve this; I'm just curious.